# How to get content of paginated pages via Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

I would like to setup `Scrapy` Python library so that it goes through all `http://www.domain.com/classifieds/something/?pg=<page>` pages, for `<page>` goes from `1 to 200`, collect all urls of the form `http://www.domain.com/classifieds/something/view/<number>/`, where `<number>` is a long number, and finaly retrieve the html code of those `urls` via `Requests` Python library?